# How to swap rows of a uint8 array?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have been working on to make data for my 50 image files after applying pixel labeling. The output I get is like this `[256*256]` starting from 0,0 in Matlab command window. But what I want is that I first get the 256 row then backwards, 256, 255, 254, ..., 1. Like this:

[image: desired outcome]

After that I want to get

```
[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]
```

`regionprops` gives us `[left top width height]` but I want to change it to `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]`.

How can I accomplish these two tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to flip the image upside-down, putting the bottom row at the top, use [`flipud`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html):

```
flipped_img = flipud(img);
```

If you want to rotate the image by 90 degrees, moving the left column to the bottom row, and the bottom row to the right column, then use [`rot90`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html):

```
rotated_img = rot90(img);
```

---

An array `p = [left top width height]` can be converted to an array `t = [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax]` by simple arithmetic. We take `xmin = left`, `ymin = top`, `xmax = xmin + width - 1` and `ymax = ymin + height - 1`:

```
t = [p(1:2), p(1:2)+p(3:4)-1];
```

Comment: Thank you. Your explanation is on point and I have already figured it out. Thanks again for giving your part

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you might want to use the function [`imrotate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html):

```
J = imrotate(I',90) %Rotates your image 90 degrees counterclockwise
```

Comment: `imrotate` allows for any arbitrary rotation angle (and require the _image processing toolbox_), but for the simple purpose of the op which is to rotate a matrix by 90 degree increments, [`rot90`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rot90.html) should be plenty sufficient and possibly faster.

Comment: Thank you @pablo and #Hoki for your timely response. I am already on rotate command but th eproblem is I want to get min max coordinates for my files. Simply rotating can not solve the issue as it is still not giving me what I want. I hope someone has done some min max task before.

Comment: Then I must say I don't understrand the question. What I posted simply mirrors your image at the middle horizontal line. The index changing is very simple `[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax] = [left top left+width top+height]`

Comment: The last one i tried and it worked.Other than that rotate command was somehow affecting my mask values. Thank you sir